# Spring Boot JPA - OneToMany relationship and database structure

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I wonder what database structure would be the best option in my case:

I have entity Questionnaire:

```
@Table(name = "questionnaire")
public class Questionnaire extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fieldStatus")
    private List<QuestionnaireField > fieldStatusList;

}
```

```
@Table(name = "questionnaire_field")
public class QuestionnaireField extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

@Column(name = "questionnaire_id")
    private Long questionnaireId;

    @Column(name = "field_id")
    private Long fieldId; //this is id related to the other table Field

@Column(name = "completed")
    private boolean completed; //because I need some additional informations like completed I think I can't use ManyToMany between Questionnaire and Field

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionnaire_id")
    private Questionnaire questionnaire;
```

As you see each `Questionnaire` can have multiple `QuestionnaireFields`, BUT each `QuestionnaireField` is of type `Field` (hence I added `private Long fieldId`). Table `Field` can have 10.000 different fields.

Summary:
one questionnaire can have e.g. 10 `Fields`, the second one 20 another `Fields` etc. To store fields related to some particular `Questionnaire` I created `QuestionnaireField` table with 2 columns: `private Long questionnaireId;` and `private Long fieldId;` . The question is if it is a good approach? That are plain columns not related to any Foreign Key... I try to find the best solution to save `Questionnaire` with related `QuestionnaireFields` that are a subset of a big `Field` table...

Comment: I would remove the explicit entity `QuestionnaireField` and replace it with a `@ManyToMany` relationship between `Questionnaire` and `Field`.

Comment: Hmmm I didn't think about it - but I need additional data in my QuestionnaireField like boolean completed

Comment: Any reason why you don't have simple `@OneToMany`-`@ManyToOne` pairs in between  `Questionnaire`, `QuestionnaireField` and `Field`?

Comment: You're right I can connect these 3 entities with @OneToMany-@ManyToOne...but then I have to use Lazy loading because I will have a quite big object connected with many entities

Comment: `@OneToMany` is LAZY by default, so... go ahead :-)